# Screen refresh time of an android device

Tags: android, textview, screen, settext

Is there a way to measure the screen refresh time of an android device?

I want to know the time spent drawing a text on the screen after calling the setText method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `onDraw` method of a `TextView` to find out when it's actually redrawn.

```
public class MyTextView extends android.widget.TextView {
    private long mUpdateTime;
    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public void mySetText(CharSequence text) {
        mUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        super.setText(text);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
        long refreshTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mUpdateTime;
        //Do something with refreshTime
    }
}
```